# Custom Sortable Meta Boxes

Tags: metabox, sort

I've looked all over and can't seem to find what I'm looking for (probably because I don't even know the terminology for what I need to do).

I need to make some custom meta boxes that are similar to how you construct menus; as in, they're draggable, re-orderable, and you can add and delete them.

I want to do the same, but for the sake of simplicity, let's just say for displaying custom text, and then drag and drop ordering it to be displayed on a page.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there isn't a wordpress method to make sortable lists like on the menus page. However it is accomplishable with jQuery UI's sortable plugin. [Here](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) is a demo on jQuery UI's site.

Comment: I was just looking into this same thing a few days ago. It's doable, but I haven't found any good code snippets to make it happen.

Comment: Did you want it nested like the menu builder in wp? Is it just to rearrange text to print out a paragraph? Can you give me a detailed explanation of what it is you're trying to accomplish?  Is this a meta box on a post, or the dashboard? If you can edit your initial question to answer my queries I may be able to knock you up a code sample when I get to work.